# How to execute migrations of plugins using Grails and database migration plugin?

Tags: grails, database-migration, grails-plugin

We have modularized our application by creating one main app and multiple plugins. Grails plugins can bring their own domain classes. But when using the database migration plugin, I was not able to find a way to execute migrations delivered by a plugin.

For example: I've a report plugin and a Report domain class. A migration file should contain the schema (for creating the table):

**report plugin:**

`+ -- grails-app/domain/com/acme/Report.groovy
          |
          + -- /migrations/changelog.groovy
                      |
                      +   /version-1.0.groovy`

How can I configure the database migration plugin to execute the changelog in the report-plugin?

I am using Grails 2.3.11 and the database migration plugin 1.4.1

Thanks for your help,

best regards,
Daniel

Answer (score 0):

You just need db migration plugin on your main app and this is automatically keep track of the domain changes for all the in-place plugins in your application.We don't need to install db migration plugin on each of the application's plugin individually.

Please make sure all the plugins which includes domain are in-place for the main app i.e the one having db migration plugin.

You can make plugins in-place by simply adding this code to your main app's BuildConfig.groovy:

```
grails.plugin.location."${pluginName}" = "${pathToYourPlugin}"
```

You can also refer this blog on [Effective Grails plugin development with in-place plugins](http://www.groovy-code.com/2014/12/effective-grails-plugin-development.html).

Comment: Thanks, but this won't work for two reasons: first, the migration plugin is not looking for any changesets in my (in-place) plugins. second: when I create a WAR file and deliver this file to a customer, why should it matters whether it's an in-place plugin or not (besides that: the created plugin is not longer an in-place plugin when the WAR file is created on Jenkins).